# trying to search in array that is json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, laravel

This is my index meth:

```
if($request->has('search')){
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $households = Household::where('household_id',"1938347-32960066")->get();
    }
```

When I use the above mentioned snippet I am getting the data, but when I try to get same data using following code, it returns empty.

```
if($request->has('search')){
        $search = $request->get('search');
        $households = Household::where('household_id', 'like', '%$search%')->get();
    }
```

Where is the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: Arvind is correct that you are currently passing the a static string into the query, i.e. you're asking ```WHERE household_id LIKE '%string%'```. After you allow string interpolation with double quotes (or concatenate) it should work. Check the value in the search parameter is what you expect.

Comment: search parameter provide the correct value, that i provide in search.

Comment: You are sure that $search contains '1938347-32960066' and that you are passing '%1938347-32960066%' as the last parameter to where()? Does it work if you do ```where('household_id', $search)```?

Comment: not work for where('household_id', $search)

Comment: Then logically $search cannot equal '1938347-32960066'. Make sure there is not a subtle difference, like a different dash/hyphen or whitespace.

Comment: its works !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes instead

```
"%$search%"
```

Or, just concate:

```
'%'.$search.'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this also:

```
 $search= "%".$search."%";

->whereRaw("household_id like '".$search."'")
```